# Liquibase: Add same columns to all tables

Tags: java, database, migration, liquibase

I would like to add the same columns to all the tables when I’m creating them using Liquibase, for example, `id` and `creation_date`. Is it possible somehow?
I know that those columns will be in each table and I really don’t want to copy-paste it to all my changelogs.

Maybe something like fragment inserting is possible in changelog files?

E.g.:

```
<createTable name=“my_table”>
    <common/><!— will be replaced by my content —>
    …
</createTable>
```

or

```
<!— will automatically add columns like common —>
<createTable name=“my_table” extends=“common”>
    …
</createTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Liquibase** doesn't work that way. **Liquibase** converts changesets to **SQL** statements. You can't do this in **SQL**, so you shouldn't be doing this in **Liquibase**. Even if it is added, in my opinion, it will be non-obvious and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Well, the question is not about extending SQL, but about extending the process of generation from xml. If Liquibase can generate a statement from the xml, I suppose it would be fair to expect to be able to extend that process somehow. Anyways, I've read somewhere about the Liquibase Extensions, maybe I should try and write one